# Selenium java window handler not working on 2nd iteration of loop

Tags: java, selenium

This whole code is enclosed in a for loop. The problem is, on the first iteration of the loop it does the operation without a problem. However, when on its 2nd operation, it does not switch to the new window and I end up getting an error that "window "" does not exist". Is this expected behavior?

```
String winHandleBefore3 = driver.getWindowHandle();
          // Perform the click operation that opens new window
           driver.findElement(By.linkText("Discount")).click();

          // Switch to new window opened
          for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
              driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
          }

          // Perform the actions on new window
          driver.findElement(By.id("tier1_l1discountamt")).clear();
          driver.findElement(By.id("tier1_l1discountamt")).sendKeys(discountAmount);




          driver.findElement(By.id("save")).click();
          // Close the new window, if that window no more required


          // Switch back to original browser (first window)
          driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore3);
```

Comment: At a time you can only switch to single window. But you are iterating for multiple windows.

Comment: You should include the loop as well in code and tell us which statement is throwing the error?

Comment: The last statement is what causes the error. Funny thing is, sometimes it's an error, sometimes it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You are not performing actions in loop , loop completes its iteration then goes to your action. As you are performing actions on multiple windows then its necessary to know on which window you want to perform which action. So if you have different action for each window then use conditional statements or if you want to perform same action on each window then follow the below code

```
// Switch to new window opened
    for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        // Perform the actions on new window
        driver.findElement(By.id("tier1_l1discountamt")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("tier1_l1discountamt")).sendKeys(
                discountAmount);
        driver.findElement(By.id("save")).click();

    }
```

if you have different action for each window then user like belwo conditional statement:

```
// Switch to new window opened
    for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
         if(driver.getTitle().equals("Window Title"){

        // Perform the actions on new window
        driver.findElement(By.id("tier1_l1discountamt")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("tier1_l1discountamt")).sendKeys(
                discountAmount);
        driver.findElement(By.id("save")).click();
       }

    }
```

I hope it will help you.